# parsing XML (selfclosed) using SimpleXML PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse some fields from a XML string. My PHP code looks like:

```
$oscam2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
//$oscam2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
$oscaa = $oscam2->status->client[2][request]['caid'];
echo $oscaa;
die(var_dump($oscaa));
```

My XML file looks like:

```
<oscam version="1.20-unstable_svn build r10649"revision="10649" starttime="2015-05-27T06:41:07-0400"uptime="954150" readonly="0">
<status>
<client type="s" name="root" desc="" protocol="server"protocolext="" au="0" thid="id_0x1d3d260">

<request caid="0000" srvid="0000" ecmtime=""ecmhistory="" answered=""/>

<times login="2015-05-27T06:41:07-0400" online="954150"idle="740499"/>

<connection ip="127.0.0.1" port="0">OK</connection>

</client>

<client type="h" name="root" desc="" protocol="http"protocolext="" au="0" thid="id_0x7f8e8c0008c0">

<request caid="0000" srvid="0000" ecmtime=""ecmhistory="" answered=""/>

<times login="2015-05-27T06:41:07-0400" online="954150"idle="0"/>

<connection ip="127.0.0.1" port="0">OK</connection>

</client>

<client type="p" name="Sky" desc="" protocol="cccam_ext (2.2.1-3316)" protocolext="OSCam v1.20-unstable_svn, build r10666 (x86_64-linux-gnu-ssl) [EXT,SID,SLP]"au="-1" thid="id_0x7f8e74006340">

<request caid="0000" srvid="0000" ecmtime=""ecmhistory="" answered=""/>

<times login="2015-06-05T15:53:12-0400" online="143425"idle="143383"/>

<connection ip="XXX"port="34010">OFF</connection>

</client>

</status>

<log>

<![CDATA[
logdata

]]>

<![CDATA[
logdata

]]>

</log>

</oscam>
```

As you see, I want to parse the content("0000") of the [request]['caid'] field of the element "Sky". Any idea how to get this done? The XML of request and times are selfclosed.

Comment: http://www.xmlvalidation.com says your XML is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do something like the following to get at the element attribute.

```
$oscam2->status->client[2]->request->attributes()['caid'];
```

if that does not work for you then you are on an older PHP version and will need to do something like this

```
$attributes = $oscam2->status->client[2]->request->attributes();
$value = $attributes['caid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check that simpleXML can read your string, because there is no spaces between attributes. When no error in parsing xml, you can use xpath to don't depend of changing order of `client` items. It takes `client` node with `name` equal `'Sky'` then inside it attribute `caid` of `request` node:

```
$oscam2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
if(!$oscam2) die("Error reading xml string");
$caid = (string)$oscam2->xpath('//client[@name="Sky"]/request/@caid')[0];
echo $caid; // 0000
```